# File/directory in the CentOS looks weird

Tags: linux, ls

I am connected to CentOS server via PuTTY and I see a weird file/directory in one of the sub-directory which looks unreal. I am not sure how the file exists there and Its not related to our work. Can anyone tell me what does the file mean?

We have a cronjob that will check MD5 values of the files in the directories, which is now failing that is failing on this sub-directory and I assuming this file could be one of the reason. Please suggest.

I see this when I do `ls -l`

[image: console screenshot]

Comment: Try running `sudo chmod -R g+x` against the directory or file and then `chmod +x` against the file or directory and see if that helps.... These answers here will be well worth reading for you as there are many other things that can cause this so read all answers and comments: https://serverfault.com/questions/65616/question-marks-showing-in-ls-of-directory-io-errors-too

Answer (score 0):

Get inode number for the file using

```
ls -li
```

You will get inode number in first column of listing.
Find file using inode number e.g.123456 and delete as below:

```
find . -inum 123456-exec rm -i {} \;
```